# CSS cut-off corners on image (<img> tag) without div

Tags: image, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to get a CSS-only solution for a cut-off bottom right corner on every image in a page.

So far, I have come up with this:

```
img::after {
    content: url(/images/whitecorner.png);
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

But the  doesn't appear in the document anywhere. (I'm using the Chrome inspector).

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cant do that with CSS alone - you can with jquery but I would go with the answer below

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?http://jsfiddle.net/h7Xb5/4/

Answer (score 7):

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pYQAX/1/)**

You can not use `::after` with `img`.

Same with `input`s, this is because they are self closing (`/>`) and hold no content.

What you could do is something like this:

```
<div class='cut-image'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/250'/>
</div>
```

and then use

```
.cut-image::after{
  /*styles*/
}
```

In my example I used:

HTML:

```
<div class='cut-image'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/250'/>
</div>

<div class='cut-image'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/250'/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cut-image{
    position:relative;
    float:left;    
    margin:0 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.cut-image::after {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-left:40px solid transparent;
    border-top:40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:40px solid white;
    border-right:40px solid white;
}
```

Comment: He didn't say anything about a background image...This or use jquery if you must.

Comment: @Prisoner - do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

`img` is an inline element and `:before` or `:after` won't work , you'll have to wrap the img with a div

this is probably what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/h7Xb5/1/

this is the css:

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px
}
div:hover:before {
    content:"";
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:url(http://www.linobanfi.it/immagini/lino_banfi_3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```