# Is it possible to cut specific parts of an image?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Sometimes images just explain things better than 1000 words

assumed the black border is my image I want to cut off the top left/right edge - like marked by the red lines.

Would it be possible (if yes: how) to cut an image this way with CSS?

Just in case its not clear what I mean by cut: I want

[image]

By cut I mean, that the image will look like this

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS cut-off corners on image (<img> tag) without div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632125/css-cut-off-corners-on-image-img-tag-without-div)

Comment: @HunterTurner: I'm not so sure this is really a duplicate. The question you linked to is using "cut off" to actually mean "place a white triangle over", whereas this question *seems* to be asking for a way to *actually* cut off parts of the image so that the background will show through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using a wrapper element, you can use [`clip-path`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path), though the support isn't great.

```css
img.cut {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50px 0, calc(100% - 50px) 0, 100% 50px, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50px);
  clip-path: polygon(50px 0, calc(100% - 50px) 0, 100% 50px, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50px);
}
```

```html
<img class="cut" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/">
```

This uses [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) ([widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)), so you can specify exact pixel values to clip by.

Answer (score 2):

### CSS Pseudo

If you know you're background is going to remain a solid colour, you can achieve this using pseudo elements in a number of ways.

**1st option**

A very simple solution is to use the pseudo elements with borders to which should get you the effect you want.

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 80px solid white;
  border-right: 80px solid red;
  width: 0;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 80px solid white;
  border-left: 80px solid red;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**2nd Option**

Using a single pseudo element which is larger than the parent and rotating it to get the desired effect.

This is a much cleaner effect and also means the use of background images is supported and easier to implement.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: red;
  left: -50%;
  top: 20px;
```

```html
<div></div>
```